Voltage Controlled Amplifier using Oscillator
I have found an example of a voltage Controlled amplifier using a square wave control on this page

I'm trying to modify it using my own control signal, a triangle wave from Low frequency oscillator. The op amps in the oscillator need to work in the 9-0V range so my triangle wave has a 4.5V DC component that is filtered by a capacitor.

I want to add this signal to the base of the transistor, but when i connect it, it drops to -1.8V. How can i have the signal centered around 0V? Thanks!


Forget it. The shown voltage controlled amp provides only 2 gain levels. Switching between them happens by switching the 10k resistor R2 to increase the gain when transistor Q1 is ON. Trying to drive it with a triangle will be unsuccessful because the transistor works non-linearly. Its input is basically a diode rectifier. Your red curve shows how the rectifier gradually allows the triangle voltage to charge the output capacitor of the triangle generator until it's fully charged with these voltage levels.
You obviously want a tremolo effect which swings the gain up and down smoothly. Find a ready to use circuit for it or experiment by using an LDR in the gain control. Let a LED get up and down ramping current to sweep smoothly the resistance of the LDR. Place the led and the LDR close each other inside a lightproof box. Or use a LDR output optocoupler like NSL-32SR3 https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1674205.pdf
The LDR could be in place of R1 or in series with it. Generally it can as well be in gain control feedback of an opamp as the other resistor in a 2 resistor attenuator.
JFETs have been useful as voltage controlled resistors, but such designs are much more difficult. Even more difficult solution is to use the logarithmic law of a diode to construct a voltage controlled amplifier. LDR is the easiest possibility for experimenting with easy to understand circuits and without any heavy math. DSP, of course, is the modern solution, but it happens only in a device which is basically a computer.

The site you link to is about a Variable Gain Amplifier (VGA), but what you want is a Voltage Controlled Amplifier (VCA).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-gain_amplifier
This is a more difficult circuit.  Old guitar amps used a junction FET (JFET) as the variable element.  Even older ones used a diode.
Search for 'voltage-controlled amplifier schematic' to get examples of how others do it.  You will see that this is not a simple task.  Some of the complexity comes from the circuit's application.  Guitar amplifiers do not demand the same level of audio fidelity as a mixing console.
There are two basic approaches.  One is to use a voltage-variable resistance such as a photomod or JFET, either as part of an attenuator or as one of the gain-setting resistors around an opamp.  The other is to use an analog multiplier circuit, where modulating the current through a gain stage changes the gain of that stage.
This page has some circuits:
http://www5b.biglobe.ne.jp/~houshu/synth/
One of them uses an Operational Transconductance Amplifier (OTA) as a voltage-controlled resistance with gain.  It is much better controlled than a light-dependent resistor.
Here are more examples:
https://www.schmitzbits.de/vca.html#
